# How to change the level of the sections with autex?

Tags: auctex

I have a document that I want to change the section to subsection, does  a key combination from AUCTeX/Emacs commands to do that  exists ?

Comment: \subsection{}???

Comment: Are we talking indentation, \thesection, or the secnumdepth counter?

Comment: Imagine we have 30 sections and we need to move them to subsections.

Comment: This will depend on the editor that you use. You probably want to use a search and replace routine.

Answer (score 3):

You can activate outline-minor-mode.
: <kbd>M-x outline-minor-mode</kbd> . Next

<kbd>C-c @ C-<</kbd>    <kbd>C-c @ C-></kbd>  to promote or demote section level

Comment: How I use @? Never see before.

Comment: @ is a very useful key. Just hit the key. Position depends on your keyboard. On international-US keyboard, top line second key from left. shift

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_and_American_keyboards#/media/File:KB_US-International.svg

Answer (score 1):

You can use **\subsection{}** instead:

```
\documentclass{a4paper}[report]
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{This is a Section}

\lipsum[2]

   \subsection{This is a subsection}
   \lipsum[2-3]

   \subsection{This is a 2nd subsection}
   \lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I know, but if I have multiple sections, how would I do it using autex.

Comment: sorry I can't help you with that.